# sourceCpp upcoming iso standard

Tags: r, rcpp

I am using Rcpp with Windows RStudio and I use to compile a Cpp code using sourceCpp(filepath). I need to compile a new code passed by a guy to me but on my PC it does not work since it turns the following error:

```
"This file requires compiler and library support for the upcoming \
ISO C++ standard, C++0x. This support is currently experimental, and must be \
enabled with the -std=c++0x or -std=gnu++0x compiler options."
```

How can I arrange it on my Workstation?
I am using `R x64 3.1.2` last version of `Rcpp` and `RcppParallel` and Windows 7 x 64 bit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to turn on C++11 support via, for example, a line

```
 // [[Rcpp::plugins(cpp11)]]`
```

See the [Rcpp Attributes](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Rcpp/vignettes/Rcpp-attributes.pdf) vignette for details and some of the [Rcpp Gallery](http://gallery.rcpp.org) posts examples.